# Develop an Azure Bot Channel

Tags: botframework, speech

Does anybody know, is it possible to develop an own Bot Channel in Azure. When I publish a bot to azure, I must choose the channel like Alexa, Directline, Speech... How can I develop my own channel?
Regards
Andreas

Answer (score 0):

You would make use of [Direct Line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-concepts?view=azure-bot-service-4.0). The Direct Line channel allows you to communicate with a bot using REST calls. You can call the API from your application if none of the other channels meet your requirements. It would be up to you to design everything around how your user interacts with the bot.